# window.orientation reports old value in onresize

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari, ipod

I'm displaying a web page on an ipod touch that shows window.orientation. It updates this text during the onresize event, and also during a timer. If I turn the ipod then the onresize event shows the old orientation, not the new orientation value. The timer always shows the correct value. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onorientationchange` is probably what you want to use.

Comment: It seems like onorientationchange is fired after onresize.